# How do you call youtube music videos composed cut scenes of speech of a public figure?

Tags: word-choice

For example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIAT0bgBWjY) kind of video. The author cut the speech scenes, as short as a vowel and as long as a phrase, to combine them to make a brand new music videos.

Comment: Did you intend to ask *what* it is is called? *How* it is called is probably via an API (off-topic at EL&U).

Comment: what it is called. I am wondering if the English community has come up with a name for this type of music video, because it's been quite popular since youtube existed, and I just learned from a Chinese friend that Chinese community actually created a word for it.

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] your question to include that information, including a transliteration if possible, in case it was phonetically derived from an English term. On Stack Exchange, comments are not considered part of the question; they are intended to help guide the editing for clarity etc. Questions need to stand on their own. Even links are just for verification; the important parts need to be expressed in the question text.

Answer (score 4):

What you’ve described sounds like a *mashup*.

> A **mashup** (also mesh, mash up, mash-up, blend, bootleg and bastard pop/rock) is a creative work, usually in a form of a song, created by blending two or more pre-recorded songs, usually by overlaying the vocal track of one song seamlessly over the instrumental track of another.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(music))

Comment: That's close, but I don't think it quite gets there - it's not specific enough. The works of people like cassetteboy, remixing politicians speech over a backing track sound like the sort of thing the OP is asking for, but "mashups" also include things like Wax Audio's *Whole Lotta Sabbath* and *Maiden Goes to Bollywood" which are all-music

Comment: ... But there may not be a better term, or at least not something short and well known

Comment: @ChrisH Now that you point it out, it might be **too** specific to music ‘remixes’. Perhaps I can claim some semantic widening :) - the editing of bits and pieces of existing work to form a new musical work seemed to point straight to *mashup*. I think I’ll let this answer stand for now, but I appreciate both comments.

Comment: It's a helpful answer and may in fact be better than the suggestion I'm about to make (+1 BTW, I thought I'd voted alreday but apparently not)

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article for [Cassetteboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassetteboy), an English act that are well-known for such videos, uses the term [*cut-ups*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-up_technique).  This was originally used with written text but has been applied to video since the 1960s and audio since the 70s.  I have a little doubt about this use as the original cut-up technique involved a random element that would be out of place in these more poltical videos.